# Pass the values from multiple select list in html form using Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, openssl

Try to run an app on local machine through virtual environment. But run into this issues related to libssl. Have libssl.1.0.0.dylib in the reference folder so I don't know why it cannot find the method. Really appreciate anyone can give me a direction.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from traffic_analytics import traffic_analytics
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/Documents/Development/giq-analytics/dashboard-x/webapp/traffic_analytics.py", line 12, in <module>
    from traffic import download_ga_data as ga_downloader
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/Documents/Development/giq-analytics/dashboard-x/webapp/traffic/download_ga_data.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ga import GoogleAnalytics
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/Documents/Development/giq-analytics/dashboard-x/webapp/traffic/ga.py", line 8, in <module>
    from apiclient import errors
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apiclient/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from googleapiclient import discovery
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 66, in <module>
    from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 46, in <module>
    from oauth2client import crypt
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/crypt.py", line 40, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 11, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 7, in <module>
    binding = Binding()
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 114, in __init__
    self._ensure_ffi_initialized()
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 126, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
    cls._modules,
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/utils.py", line 31, in load_library_for_binding
    lib = ffi.verifier.load_library()
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/verifier.py", line 97, in load_library
    return self._load_library()
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/verifier.py", line 207, in _load_library
    return self._vengine.load_library()
  File "/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/vengine_cpy.py", line 153, in load_library
    raise ffiplatform.VerificationError(error)
cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: importing '/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_f3e4673fx399b1113.so': dlopen(/Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_f3e4673fx399b1113.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method
  Referenced from: /Users/zhehaozhou/anaconda/envs/virtualZhehao2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_f3e4673fx399b1113.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```